# On parallel execution - which side reports about an error?

Tags: kdb, k

When using different methods (sync/async) to callback a caller process I'm getting an error on different sides:

```
$ q -p 1234  │$ q
             │q)h:hopen`::1234;
             │q)neg[h]({.z.w x};42)
q)'type      │
             │q)neg[h]({neg[.z.w] x};42)
             │q)'type
             │
             │q)neg[h]({neg[.z.w] x};42); h[]
             │42
```

Could you explain this behavior for 1st and 2nd cases please? Why does an exception raize on the 2nd process with the sync callback command `.z.w x`, and on the caller with the `neg[.z.w]` callback?

And for the 3rd case: is this something like a pattern (or common use case in IPC) to chase async calls with 'sync' handles with empty args `h[]`/`h(::)` to get the results back making such *ad-hock handlers* for them?

---

**Upd:**
Does *blocking receive* construct replaces `.z.ps/.z.pg` calls?

---

**Upd2:**
If there exists *deferred synchronous* - is there something like *deferred asynchronous*?

---

Asked about **Upd** and **Upd2** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115623).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should help clarify on what's happening

**case 1:**
This gives the appearance of failing on the remote but it's not. It's being evaluated on the remote to '.z.w 42' which sends a sync message back to the local process, where it's evaluated by .z.pg (whose default definition is `value`). 'value 42' results in a type error which is returned to the remote.

```
q)h:hopen 1234
q).z.pg:{value x};system"e 1"
q)neg[h]({.z.w x};42)
q)'type
  [0]  .z.pg:{value x}
              ^
q))
```

**case 2:**
again the evaluation of 'value 42' (this time by .z.ps - whose default definition is also `value`) fails with a type error but as it's async it's not returned to the sending process

```
q).z.ps:{value x}
q)
q)neg[h]({neg[.z.w] x};42)
q)'type
  [0]  .z.ps:{value x}
              ^
q))
```

**case 3:**
This is a method of IPC communication known as *deferred synchronous*. We block/listen/hang on the connection after sending the async message, awaiting a response, using a construct known as a *blocking receive*

```
q)neg[h]({neg[.z.w] x};42);h[]
42
```

In some cases it may not be necessary to hang on the connection i.e. if the callback invokes another function like so

```
q)neg[h]({neg[.z.w](0N!;x)};42);
q)42

q)add:(0N!10+);neg[h]({neg[.z.w](`add;x)};42);
q)52
```

Deferred synchronous messaging is used in mserve.q here - https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/e/mserve.q